# Subqueries mixed with Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to figure out this query and it is confusing me. The goal is to Create a SQL query to display: Scholarship_Name, Average Amount Awarded. I will link the tables below, along with the query i have made so far in hopes someone can point out what im doing wrong.

I would like to point out that the two tables dont have any PK or FK in common so thats why i linked them the way i did. So far what I have made in the query brings up the names but when i try to average the amounts they go to 0.0 . Im stumped and have been googling all day. Any help would be appreciated.

SCHOLARSHIPS

ID/ SCHOLARSHIP_NAME / AMOUNT_AVAILABLE

```
"1" "Presidents Award"  "$15,000"

"2" "Chancellor Academic Award" "$25,000"

"3" "Chevron Award" "$20,000"
```

SCHOLARSHIP_AWARDS

ID / SCHOLARSHIP_ID / STUDENT_ID / AMOUNT_AWARDED

```
"1" "2" "9" "$1,500"

"2" "3" "8" "$1,500"

"3" "1" "7" "$2,000"

"4" "2" "6" "$1,500"

"5" "2" "5" "$3,000"

"6" "3" "4" "$5,000"

"7" "3" "3" "$2,500"

"8" "2" "2" "$2,500"

"9" "1" "1" "$1,500"
```

Query:

```
SELECT Scholarships.SCHOLARSHIP_NAME, AVG(Scholarship_Awards.Amount_Awarded) AS "Average Amount Awarded"
FROM Scholarships JOIN Scholarship_Awards
ON Scholarship_Awards.SCHOLARSHIP_ID = SCHOLARSHIPS.ID
GROUP BY SCHOLARSHIP_NAME
```

Comment: Are the scholarship amounts stored as strings? `$1,500`, `$2,500` and so on? If so the database engine might not be able to aggregate the strings properly. What RDBMS are you using? Also, you're not using a subquery here. You should consider removing that tag, and possibly editing your question title.

Comment: @PatrickTucci I dont believe they are strings because some are split up differently depending how many students got the scholarship and how much the max of the scholarship was. The school is making us use SQLite3 in DBrowser. I will try and figure out how to change them. Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.